# Is it possible to use a FormEditor in an e4 application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there a way to use a [FormEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fforms%2Feditor%2FFormEditor.html) in an e4 application? I want to migrate an 3.x Eclipse RCP application to e4 and it would be great if there would be a simple way to reuse existing editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use any editor based on the 3.x `EditorPart`.

I think you can use the `org.eclipse.ui.forms` plug-in that contains things like `FormToolkit`, but I have not tried this. The dependencies for this plug-in only contain optional dependencies on 3.x code.